# Send custom object as response along with status code 200 on successful login without internal redirection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to return user detail object (custom object) as a response to the client once the user is authenticated. I have configured a `customSuccessHandler` for this but I am not sure how do I send object in response without redirecting it from the `handle()` method.

Initially I redirected it to another method annotated with `@RequestMapping("/user")`, but this sent the response status as 302 (redirection) which is not acceptable to the client side (Angular UI).Other option I have is to ask Ui to make another request to (`"/user"`) and get the required details, but this would cause and unnecessary over burden on client to make and extra rest call. Is there a better way of achieving this?

my `handle()` method in `CustomSuccessHandler`

```
@Override
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);     
    Users user = getUserDetails(); //this gets the user details
    session.setAttribute("user",user); 
    response.getWriter().append("OK");
    response.setStatus(200);
}
```

The functionality I am trying to achieve is on successful user login, my back-end code should reply with status code `200` and also the user details without any extra REST call.

Comment: ”Is not acceptable to the client side” what do you mean?

Comment: I see that you have put the `user` object in session. Does this not solve your purpose? Can the client not access it from there?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, the ui team says its a unnecessary rest call.The same task can be done after successful login.

Comment: the ui team knows nothing about rest. `@Post` /login and get a user object back is not restful. It semantically doesn't make any sense. `@Get` /user and get a user object back makes sense.

Comment: just because you can do it, doesn't mean it is right or best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is the best practice but as you can do this in your `handle(..)`

```
response.getWriter().append("OK");
```

you can do also this:

```
User user = getUserDetails();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
response.getWriter().append(om.writeValueAsString(user));
```

remembering that you should of course use some DTO for user details written to response that does not expose password or any other sensitive data.

Comment: creating a ObjectMapper on each rest call is very bad practice since ObjectMappers are large memory hungry objects and brings down performance.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Correct, that was only for example. Adding it as `@Resource ObjectMapper om` in `CustomSuccessHandler` is the correct way to obtain it.